# what is ... syntax? (found in Angular2)

Tags: angular

I don't know if this syntax or symbol or whatever belongs to `Angular2` or something else...

but I wonder with,

what **`...`** syntax is and how it works behind the scene?

```
ngOnChanges(...args:any[])
{
   console.log(args);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the [TypeScript rest operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3922-parameter-list). In this case, it means any number of arguments of any type can occur there; the function will see them as an array of `any`. (JavaScript recently got rest and spread operators as well, as of ES2015, but the `:any[]` in your example tells us this is TypeScript.)

E.g.:

```
ngOnChanges('a', 42, null);
```

...would show

```
["a", 42, null]
```

in the console.

Here's a complete example ([live copy](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20foo(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%09console.log(%22args.length%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20args.length)%3B%0A%09args.forEach((arg%3Aany%2C%20index%3ANumber)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(%22args%5B%22%20%2B%20index%20%2B%20%22%5D%3A%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%09%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afoo('a'%2C%2042%2C%20null)%3B)):

```
function foo(...args:any[]) {
    console.log("args.length = " + args.length);
    args.forEach((arg:any, index:Number) => {
        console.log("args[" + index + "]: " + arg);
    });
}
foo('a', 42, null);
```

outputs

```
args.length = 3
args[0]: a
args[1]: 42
args[2]: null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 3):

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

```
function(a, b, ...theArgs) {
  // ...
}
```

> If the last named argument of a function is prefixed with ..., it becomes an array whose elements from 0 to theArgs.length are supplied by the actual arguments passed to the function.
>
> In the above example, theArgs would collect the third argument of the function (because the first one is mapped to a, and the second to b) and all the consecutive arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

It's the ES2015 spread operator (or ellipsis operator). This allows to destructuring array.

For example:

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) {
  // x = 0, y = 1, z = 2
}

var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);
```

See this link for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator
- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html
- http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook